# Spring Actuator http, but Embeded servlet https

Tags: java, spring, ssl, https, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot with embedded servlet container on 8080 port and actuator on 9001 port.
It is possible to turn off ssl on spring actuator port when the embedded servlet container use ssl?

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment, no. There's a [hack described in this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3509#issuecomment-152051942). However, I'm not sure I'd recommend using it so I won't add the details here.

If this is an enhancement that you'd like to see, please [open a Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new).